# What does this error mean: variable-size type declared outside of any function

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a function, `fx` named and has two input variable as an array and a double, so I wrote my program like this and I am faced with below error. The problem is in definition of input array but I don't know how to solve it.
And another problem is when I want to call this `fx` function with inputs, how can I give a complete array as the first input variable — `fx(matris[n],x)`?

```
error : variable-size type declared outside of any function
```

Code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int n=1;
double y=1;
double x;
double fx(double matris[], double x){
double f = 0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)//e.g f(X)= 3x^2 + 2x -4 = 0 [3 2 -4]
{
        y = 1;
        for(int k = 0;k<n-i-1;k++){//temp: y = x*x*x or x*x or x ... (calcules powers)
        y = y*x;
        }       
        f = f+y*matris[i];// 3 * y((x*x)) + 2 * y((x)) +  -4* y(1)
}
return f;
}
double dif(double matris[], double x){
double temp[n];
temp[0] = 0;
for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
temp [i+1] = matris[i] * (n-i-1);
}
return fx(temp[n], x);
}
int main(){
//newton-raphson method to solve a equilibrium
cout << "please enter the degree of your equilibrium: ";
cin >> n;
double matris[n];
cout << "please enter your equlibruim array: ";
for(int i =0; i<n; i++)
cin >> matris[i];

//x = x0 - f(x)/f'(x);
x = 1;
fx(matris,x);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: It appears you edited your code to 'fix' it per the answer. Please do not do that. It is very confusing for people who find this in the future. Rather, amend your post with comments about the fix and or add a corrected copy of the code, while leaving the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since arrays passed to a function don't actually have a size (variable or otherwise), the compiler objects to you passing a variable `n` as the size of `matris`.

Just remove the `n` from your `double matris[n]` expression, leaving the square brackets empty.

[Note that the code doing `cin > n; double matris[n];` is not standards compliant C++ - C++14 will introduce such a concept, but for existing C++ standards, it is not allowed - only GNU C++ and some "GNU C++ compatible" compilers support this construct].

Comment: ty!!!
the first problem solved :D
but i have an error now in :    return fx(temp[n], x);
As:
cannot convert `double' to `double*' for argument `1' to `double fx(double*, double)'

Comment: Just use `return fx(temp, x);`, but consider upgrading the function to take the array size as a parameter: `double fx(int n, double matrix[], double x);`.  Global variables such as `n` are nasty!

Comment: Again, you can't pass an array of a "certain size", you just pass the entire array - `fx(temp, x)`;

Comment: You should accept this answer if that solved the problem. It is the stackoverflow way.

Comment: Actually, you can't pass arrays to a function *at all*. If you declare a parameter of array type, it's adjusted to a pointer to the element type. This: `void func(int array[42]);` really means: `void func(int *array);` (and the fact that the `42` is silently ignored is one of the nastier features of both C and C++).

Comment: MSVC has also had the VLA language extension in C++ for a long time, and I wouldn't call it "GNU C++ compatible".

Comment: Hmm. I thought MSVC only supported C style VLA's, where G++ supports "any type", so there's a difference. But in this case, it may not make any difference. Either way, it's non-standard.